Diseases & Bayes Theorem
I am trying to solve the following problem:

The probability that an individual randomly selected from a particular population has a certain disease is $0.05$. A diagnostic test correctly detects the presence of the disease $98\%$ of the time and correctly detects the absence of the disease $99\%$ of the time. If the test is applied twice, the two test results are independent, and both are positive, what is the (posterior) probability that the selected individual has the disease?

Let $d$ be the event that person is diseased, $+$ be the event that positive test occurs.
By the definition of conditional probability,
$$
\newcommand{\and}{\mathbin{\mathrm{and}}}
P(d \mid + \and +) = \frac{P(d \and + \and +)}{P(+ \and +)}. 
$$
I am not sure how to find the denominator correctly. I was first trying to find that
$$
\begin{aligned}
P(+) &= P(+ \and \lnot d) + P(+ \and d) \\
&= P(+ \mid \lnot d) \, P(\lnot d) + P(+ \mid d) \, P(d) \\
&= 0.01 \cdot 0.95 + 0.98 \cdot 0.05.
\end{aligned}
$$
Then, since the problem says that the tests are independent of each other, I am trying to find
$$
P(+ \and +) = P(+) \cdot P(+), 
$$
but this is not giving the correct answer, but I am not sure why.
I know
$$
\begin{aligned} 
P(+ \and +) &= P(+ \and + \and \lnot d) + P(+ \and + \and d) \\
&= P(\lnot d) \, P(+ \and + \mid \lnot d) 
+ P(d) \, P(+ \and + \mid d). 
\end{aligned}
$$
I then tried
$$
\begin{aligned}
P(+ \and + \mid d) &= 0.98 \cdot 0.98 = 0.9604, \\
P(+ \and + \mid \lnot d) &= (1 - 0.99) \cdot (1 - 0.99), 
\end{aligned}
$$
and plugged in $P(d)$ and $P(\lnot d)$, I got the correct denominator.
Based on this, it seems to me that we can do
$$
P(+ \and + \mid d) = P(+ \mid d)^2
$$
but not
$$
P(+ \and +) = P(+)^2
$$
(with $P(+)$ described as above).
I would appreciate any clarification on this issue, and guidance on how to proceed.
EDIT: I would also appreciate if someone could clarify the intuition behind why the two formulas differ and why the top one is the one that works.

Your first line that says "By Bayes's Theorem" is incorrect. That is the definition of conditional probability.

Let $T$ be the event that the patient tested positive twice and $D$ be the event that they have the disease.
Then, by Bayes' theorem,
$$P(D|T)=\frac{P(T|D)P(D)}{P(T|D)P(D)+P(T|\lnot D)P(\lnot D)}=\frac{(0.98)^2(.05)}{(0.98)^2(.05) + (.01)^2(0.95)}$$

Yes, the problem is badly worded.  It should clarify that tests are independent for the given person.  Meaning conditionally independent.

The person has the same state during the two tests.

If the person has the disease, then both tests each have a $98\%$ chance give a true positive result, independently.
$$\mathsf P(+\text{ and }+\mid d)=\mathsf P(+\mid d)^2$$

If the person does not have it, then both tests each have a $1\%$ chance to give a false positive result, independently.
$$\mathsf P(+\text{ and }+\mid\neg d)=\mathsf P(+\mid\neg d)^2$$



so:$$\mathsf P(d\mid +\text{ and }+) = \dfrac{\mathsf P(d)\,\mathsf P(+\mid d)^2}{\mathsf P(d)\,\mathsf P(+\mid d)^2+\mathsf P(\neg d)\,\mathsf P(\neg d\mid +)^2}$$



I always try to solve these problems by getting concrete.  Assume $200000$ different trials.  In $10000$ of those trials, you'll have a sick person and in the other $190000$ trials the person isn't sick.
When you perform two tests on the non-sick persons, you'll get two false positives in $19$ of those trials.  When you perform two tests on the sick persons, you'll get at least one false negative $396$ times, so you'll get two true positives $9604$ times.
Thus, given two positive results, the probability that your test subject really is sick is $\dfrac{9604}{9604+19} \approx 0.998$.
